# How to allow directory imports with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js v14.8.0 and ES6 style module imports.

My code looks like this:

```
import myModule from "./my-module";
```

**Expected behaviour:**

The file `./my-module/index.js` is imported.

**Actual behaviour:**

Node.js throws the `ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT` error.

**Question:**

How can I configure node.js to allow directory imports and resolve them using the index.js file?

Comment: its not supported, either include `index` or make it a module/package, see this example: https://github.com/lcherone/nested_npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: "vanilla" node.js doesn't support this.

We decided to use babel, which allows for this notation.